# how to save whole response message in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am receiving below response in jmeter-

[{"Status":"Failed","ErrorDesc":"Duplicate Transaction Id","Amount":"23","CorporateID":"aaa","StatusCode":"ERR0DUP","TransactionReferenceNumber":"1111"}]

I need to save this whole response message.
I tried by using listner,and using csv file as well but only b able to save response like - OK,true

Please help me to save whole response as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Save the Response to a File Sampler with following configuration
[image]

1. Ensure "**Don't add number to prefix**" check box is not checked
2. Set the **Minimum Length of sequence number** (e.g 6)

You can try with following options for unique file names

1. Check the **Add timestamp**
2. Use **${__threadNum}** and/or **${__threadGroupName}** fields with file name

   response-${__threadGroupName}-{__threadNum}.json

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save response into a variable just use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) with empty left and right boundaries or [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and `(?s)(^.*)` regular expression, see [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) article for more details to learn more about differences of these two guys.

Example setup:

[image]

in the above setup the whole response will be saved into a JMeter Variable and you will be able to refer it as `${response}` where required

If you want to save response into a file - go for [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener, add it as a child of the request which returns the response and configure it like:

[image]

the above configuration will store the whole response of the parent sampler into `response.txt` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

Comment: Working fine now,but its overlapping the response on previous response,any solution for that?

Comment: Please help us ,its urgent

Comment: Thanks..it's working now..used jsr223 listner with code to write results in a file.

Comment: Your file name has to dynamic. This could be achieved by unchecking "Don't add number to prefix and checking Add timestamp checkbox.